# GitHub asks me to "add a new helper tool" every time I open it

Tags: osx-yosemite, github-for-mac

Every time I open GitHub for Mac it asks me to "add a new helper tool" and prompts me for my password.  Every time I enter my password (I am an admin on this computer) but I see no noticeable changes afterwards and the prompt comes back every time I reopen GitHub.  (See attached photo for the prompt window.)

I am running OSX Yosemite Version 10.10 on a Late 2012 Mac Mini (2.5 GHz Intel Core i5).

Unsure if this is related but I am running GitHub version "Reactive Barbecue (186)".  According to [the GitHub for Mac release notes](https://mac.github.com/release-notes.html) this is NOT the newest version, but when I select "Check for updates" it says I have the latest version.  Would a fresh install of GitHub solve this?  This is more of a nuisance and doesn't noticeably impede my work.

I use GitHub daily for XCode pushes with my coworkers.  They all use MacBook Airs and OSX Yosemite but do not have the same issue as me.

[image: GitHub prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found so far was to delete the GitHub for Mac application.  Then I re-downloaded the app (the most recent version 193 "Big Feels").

It then gave me a popup saying I needed to uninstall the old version since OSX now comes with Git commands by default (or something like that?).  Clicking "Uninstall now" made the app crash so I had to select "Uninstall later".  This is sort of only a fix for the symptom since GitHub could keep telling me to uninstall every time I open it, but at least it says I have the most recent version now.

Comment: I'm having recent version 210 "Bae's branch". Still It keeps asking me the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this problem.

**Cause?** Maybe `GitHub.app` was confused by multiple git installations: XCode's Command Line Tools and Homebrew's copy (a newer version and includes bash completion).

Running the shell command `git credential-osxkeychain` returned a "usage" line, so a helper was installed despite that message.

**Fix:** Downloading and running [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) successfully installed its helper. I think `GitHub Desktop.app` is the new name for `GitHub.app`, so apparently they fixed the bug by now.

**BTW:** They [wrote](https://github.com/blog/2046-github-desktop-is-now-available#merge-and-deploy) "If you're using GitHub for Mac or Windows, the upgrade is automatic.", but their automatic upgrade didn't fix this problem nor switch to "GitHub Desktop.app".

Comment: Heh, this is a year old and I just ran into it. Installing and using `Github Desktop` rather than `Github` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCleaner and nuke it. Reinstall.

Comment: Just did it. Still having the problem.

Comment: @Isuru did you use AppCleaner? Empty the trash. Log out and back in again. It worked for me. Also make sure you're running the latest version of the github app. Hope it helps.